# Exception in fgrep command

Tags: java, grep

I want to find files in local directory which contain word:

```
fgrep word *
```

I dont understand how I can I got this exception: `fgrep: *: No such file or directory`

UPDATE:

I run this code from java:

```
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process = runtime.exec(command);
```

when I try command `ls` everything is OK

Comment: It looks like a problem of your shell expansion. What shell are you using?

Comment: I run this command from java code:             Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process process = runtime.exec(command);

Comment: The `*` expansion is done by shells like bash, this is not done by exec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ProcessBuilder works too:

```
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", command);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
fgrep word *
```

Then change permissions

```
chmod +x myscript.sh
```

And call with `runtime.exec("myscript.sh");`

Or... **better** solution: write a java function that iterate through all files in the directory and call `runtime.exec("fgrep word " + filename);`

Or... **better better** solution: do not use `fgrep` at all and do all your [search stuff with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697833/find-all-string-the-in-in-txt-file)