# Faster way of searching a String in a .txt

Tags: java

Hey guys i have written this code for searching a string in a txt file.
Is it possible to optimize the code so that it searches for the string in fastest manner possible.
Assuming the text file would be a large one (500MB - 1GB)

I dont want to use pattern Matchers.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class StringFinder {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double count = 0,countBuffer=0,countLine=0;
    String lineNumber = "";
    String filePath = "C:\\Users\\allen\\Desktop\\TestText.txt";
    BufferedReader br;
    String inputSearch = "are";
    String line = "";

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        try {
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                countLine++;
                //System.out.println(line);
                String[] words = line.split(" ");

                for (String word : words) {
                  if (word.equals(inputSearch)) {
                    count++;
                    countBuffer++;
                  }
                }

                if(countBuffer > 0)
                {
                    countBuffer = 0;
                    lineNumber += countLine + ",";
                }

            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Times found at--"+count);
    System.out.println("Word found at--"+lineNumber);
}
}
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697833/find-all-string-the-in-in-txt-file?rq=1

Comment: Better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You're on the right track. `BufferedReader` will read in data the fastest, it's up to YOU to optimize the searching algorithm.

Comment: First, don't use `line.split()`, but `line.indexOf()`.

Comment: @Thanh Le: No i dont want to include pattern
Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Try: line.indexOf(inputSearch), I thinks it faster than your loop and split :)

Comment: Make `lineNumber` a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead as it is more efficient than string concatenation.

Comment: @ThanhLe index search just return the first match found. What if the string occurs more than once in the line.

Comment: @AllenSavio You'll need to keep calling indexOf until it returns -1.

Answer (score 2):

There are [fast string search algorithms](https://www.google.com/search?q=fast%20string%20search), but a big part of the time will go into reading the file from external storage. If you can index the file ahead of time, you can save reading and scanning the entire file. If you can't, perhaps you can at least avoid reading the file from external storage, e.g. if the file came in from the network, then search it before or instead of writing it to storage.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Matcher.find`, splitting is slow since it creates a lot of objects

Comment: i dont want to include pattern matchers. Thanks :)

Comment: @Evgeniy Because i want to find a string without using regexes and pattern matchers.

Comment: @AllenSavio: If the pattern is a simple string. The matcher will work as the `Rabin-Karp` algorithm with a very small overhead compared to a native implementation (perhaps even better since sometimes these algorithms are written in a low-level language instead of Java).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `Matcher.find` for some reason, then at least go for using indexOf.

You can check on the whole line without breaking up the line into a lot of String Objects which then need iterating over.

```
int index = line.indexOf (inputSearch);

while (index != -1)
{
    count++;
    countBuffer++;
    index = line.indexOf (inputSearch, index+1);
}
```

Comment: What if they are more than one occurrences of the String in that line?

Comment: The problem is that the word searched is "are", so it can be part of another word (like care). So, if you use `indexOf()`, you may want to search for " are " instead, and add a `startsWith("are ")` and a `endsWith(" are")` call.

Comment: That is where the `while` loop and `index = line.indexOf (inputSearch, index+1);` come into play.  But using my method you bypass dealing with the line unless it has at least one occurrence.

Comment: @FlorentBayle good point, but easy enough to pad the word with spaces.  i.e. "dog" -> " dog ";

Comment: @user2310289 That's exactly what I was saying, pad the word. But, in that case you also have to check the beginning and the end of the string (because there will be no space at the beginning and no space at the end) with `startsWith()` and `endsWith()`. You may also want to check if the whole string is `equals()` to your word, just in case.

Comment: If you just want an easy speedup and you're sure that the input words are separated with spaces, you can put a space on each end of an input line and on each end of the search word, then use this `indexOf()` loop. If on the other hand, the words may have other separators like commas and periods, then use a RegExp. It's not hard. E.g. search for `"\\bare\\b"`. \b matches a word boundary, and you need a double \ to quote a \ in a Java string literal.

Answer (score 0):

For a plain string, i.e., not a regex, and if you can't index the file first using some sophisticated engine (Lucene or Solr come to mind for such a large file) or database (?), you should check out the [Rabin-Karp algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm). It's  a very clever algorithm that finds a simple string match in O(n+m) where n is the length of the text and m the length of the search string.

Answer (score 0):

Your bottleneck may not be the time it takes to parse each line at all, but reading the actual file.  Disk IO is at least an order of magnitude slower than iterating thru a char array.   But you really won't know until you profile your code.   Fire up [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/profiler.html) and use it to figure out where you are spending the most time.  If you don't, you're just guessing.